# Protect foldmarkers in Vim

Tags: vim

I have recently joined a software company that uses folded Emacs along with its own in-house compiler with additional checks for fold-structure, amongst other things. In particular, a compiler error is raised if incorrect foldmarkers are recognised (we use the foldmarks //{{{,//}}} ). As a long-time Vim user, I have been diligently writing my own Vimscript to emulate the Emacs mods.

The Emacs configuration prevents foldmarks from being edited "by hand" (e.g. accidental spaces, etc). Is there a way to achieve this in Vim? Once a foldmarker has been entered using zf, I don't want to be able to edit it manually.

Or am I pushing Vim too far? Surely not!

Thanks for your help.

Jonathan.

Comment: Foldmarkers are just text, and afaik vim does nothing to prevent you from editing that text.

Comment: What you could do is to invoke a function at BuFWritePre, i.e. just before saving the file, that would check for example there is the same number of opening and closing folder marks. And if not it should display a warning, or make it impossible to save the file if possible. I am not good enough in Vim script to propose a solution but it should be possible.

Comment: Thanks Xavier - that sounds like a sensible approach. I shall investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing edits to parts of the buffer is hard to achieve. Apart from the "fold consistency check" already mentioned in the comments (to be executed before saving the buffer), an easy way is to highlight fold markers used in the wrong places as errors (like some syntaxes (vim, sh) do for illegal elements).

You can add these either by extending the filetype's syntax (if this is only for one / a few filetypes, and embedding the new syntax group in the existing comment groups is easy) via `:syntax match ...`, or for each window via `matchadd()`.